# Central limit theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

At first glance you would think this question was easy. It's not. Maybe the answer in the back of the book is wrong. But nobody, not even my maths teacher can explain it to me.

Here is the question: an unbiased 6 sided dice is thrown 70 times. Find the probability that the mean score is less than 3.3 
Answer: 0.155

My working. 
Mean of one dice is 3.5 variance is 35/12

Therefore the mean of 70 throws is distributed normally ~N(3.5,(35/12)/70)

P(Xmean<3.3)=P(z<-0.2/0.204)
1-p(z<0.98039)
1-0.83655
0.16345
NOT THE ANSWER???

I know this isn't the most intellectually stimulating question out there but to anyone reading this it would help me out a lot if I could have this question explained to me. Thanks

Update: Maybe I am being silly and missing something very obvious. Here is the original question. [image]

Comment: @DougM as in the question, the book's answer is 0.155

Comment: 0.155 is the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result of one throw has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$,  the sum of $70$ independent throws has mean $70 \mu$ and variance $70 \sigma^2$, and the average $X$ of these $70$ throws has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2/70$.  It is **wrong** to say $X$ is distributed normally, but because of the CLT you can say it is distributed approximately normally.  Thus
$$ P(X < 3.3) \approx P\left(Z < \frac{3.3 - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{70}} \approx -0.9798\right) \approx .16359 $$

However, we might improve the result with the "continuity correction".  An average $< 3.3$ means a sum $< 70 \times 3.3 = 231$, and this sum is an integer; since the $<$ means we **don't** want to include cases where the sum is exactly $231$, we might replace $231$ by $230.5$, and thus replace $3.3$ by $230.5/70$.  This makes the 
$z$ score

$$ \frac{230.5/70 - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{70}} \approx -1.01479$$

and now indeed $$P(X < 3.3) \approx 0.155103 $$

By the way, the exact answer (not using any approximation) turns out to be
$$ \frac{229642652203521128605439312834749816684648611425676955}{1477602207273840622329353829895227690835664661525823488} \approx .1554157479$$

Comment: Right it's an approximation yes. But the answer is apparently 0.155 and I get 0.16345 so I must be doing Something wrong

Comment: Holy crap it was just a continuity correction. What a difference it makes thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When we use the normal distribution we are assuming that distributions are continuous.

If the average on 70 rolls is 3.3 then the sum is 231

P(average < 3.3) = P(sum < 231)

We need to make an adjustment for the possibility that the sum exactly equals 231

$P(x \le 231) - P(x = 231 \pm 0.5)\\
N( \frac {(230.5-245)}{\sqrt {70\cdot \frac {35}{12}}}) \approx N(-1.0148)  \approx 0.155$